# Некорректный regexp url

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет знатоки regexp выражений.

Есть выражение `/^(https:\/\/|http:\/\/)(([a-z0-9A-Z-_]){1,100}.){1,6}(.+?)$/` для проверки url.

Проблема в том, что он пропускает все символы (после http(s)://), а надо чтобы только буквы, цифры и `_`.

Например: `http://eamp;le.com` или `http://eamp;;+le.co"m` не должны быть валидными.

Comment: [0-9A-Za-z_] так работает?

Comment: @Эникейщик все равно пропускает ненужные символы.

Comment: Нечего издеваться на url'ом.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
```